# Images from url in UITableViewCell loads only when i scroll the table view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimage, nsurlrequest

Images downloaded from url displays image in UITableViewCell only when i start scrolling the UITableView. Now i am using following code to load image from url:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
        queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
        completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
            NSData * data,
            NSError * error) {
    if (!error){
            NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        // do whatever you want with image
    }

}];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you calling this code from? Can you add your tableView updating method?

Comment: I am using this code in cell for row at indexpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be getting your images in `- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` you should create a utility class that acts as backing datastore. As you code stands now you could conceivable be re-requesting the image multiple times as the cell is scrolled into and out of view.

Answer (score 0):

I Strongly recommend [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), which is very simple and powerful.

You can use `setImageWithURL` category , simply set image for imageView. For example

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];`
```

And you can simply save your image cache by `[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] storeImage:myImage forKey:myImageCacheKey]` and simply query your image cache by `[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] queryDiskCacheForKey:myImageCacheKey done:^doneBlock]`;

Very simple and powerful, for more details checkout the here [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage);